# ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'CKEditor' not found

Tags: php, kohana, ckeditor

Здравствуйте!
Нужно на сайт встроить `WYSIWYG`-редактор. Выбор пал на `CKEditor`. Проект на `kohana 3.2.`

Нашёл модуль с `CKEditor`. Подключил его в `bootstrap`:

```
Kohana::modules(array(
     ...
     'ckeditor'   => MODPATH.'ckeditor',      // ckeditor
     ...
    ));
```

в контроллере с редактированием страницы:

```
$ckeditor = new CKEditor(MODPATH.'/ckeditor');
$ckeditor->returnOutput = TRUE;
$content = ORM::factory('contact');
$ckeditor->editor('ckeditor', $content->content);
$this->template->content = $view;
$this->template->content = $ckeditor;
```

а на экране получаю

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'CKEditor' not found

не подскажете куда копать?

Comment: Так о не смог заставить работать с помощью PHP. Пришлось средствами JS это делать. Работает. Но буду думать как заставить работать через PHP.

Вопрос можно закрыть. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не думаю что нужно создавать класс CKeditor,так как это визуальный редактор и он генерируеться посредством javascript-а. просто нужно указать в каком блоге встраивать элементы визуальных контролов(по крайней мере так делають TinyMCE)
Попробуйте [вот здесь посмотреть](http://www.sdelaysite.com/php/php-23)

PS: Мне тоже интересно, так как тоже начал дружить с этим фреймворком))

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл как это сделать, расширением класса `FORM` и добавлением метода `wysiwyg` =)

Вопрос можно закрывать.